# Google Wallet Malformed URL Component

Tags: android-pay, malformedurlexception

I'm trying to implement Google Wallet to a project I'm working on.
When I press the button that's supposed to go to the sandbox checkout website, an error is generated.

```
<error xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2" serial-number="f9090666-5c3e-4e40-b1db-aeba824aa7d6">
    <error-message>
Malformed URL component: expected agent:, but got Merchant
    </error-message>
</error>
```

my code is

```
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
        <input type="image" name="Google Checkout" alt="Fast checkout through Google" src="https://checkout.google.com/buttons/checkout.gif?merchant_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&w=180&h=46&style=white&variant=text&loc=en_US">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that [Google Checkout will be retired in 11/2013](https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/3080449), a couple of months away...

As far as your code is concerned, assuming you're still curious, see [HTML documentation](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_Overview)

If you want to learn about other/newer payment solutions from Google, you'll find them at [Google Developers Commerce APIs](https://developers.google.com/commerce/)

Comment: I just emailed google and asked them if I was able to continue using the google wallet api for our project, but it seems they only support digital goods solds on Google store

Comment: @Young-kyuQHan There's `Instant Buy` [API](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/instant-buy/) though it is very different from Checkout.....